# Using structuremap in a webesrvice, how to register the types?

Tags: wcf, web-services, structuremap

I have a WCF service and need to register my interfaces and my classes with structuremap, in a regular asp.net application I would do it in global.cs in `onApplicationstartup` since this is called before anything else, but where do I initialize my structuremap in a webservice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple options:

- Put your Structuremap code in a static variable that is initialized on first access
- Use a custom ServiceHostFactory which initializes the library before creating a ServiceHost.
- Create a custom WCF ServiceBehavior which does the initialization, and apply that to all relevant services inside the ServiceLibrary.

Comment: Here is a sample project for those looking   https://github.com/billCreativeD/WCF_With_DI